# How to convert a single character to a single byte?

Tags: go, byte

I am trying to check if a given character is present in a byte:

```
//readBuf: []byte
//n: int
for i:=0;i<n;i++{
    if readBuf[i]=="?"{
        return true
    }
}
```

"?" is of type string, so I am getting an error, since readBuf[i] is a byte. How can I convert "?" to a byte to be able to compare it to readBuf[i]?

It seems that []byte("?")[0] is working (convert the 1-element string to 1-element byte array, the extract the first value), but I am sure this is not the correct way of doing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [rune literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Rune_literals) `'?'` is the untyped integer value of the question mark rune.

Use [bytes.ContainsRune](https://godoc.org/bytes#ContainsRune):

```
if bytes.ContainsRune(readBuf[:n], '?') {
   return true
}
```

Because the character `?` is encoded as a single byte in UTF-8, the test can also be written as:

```
for _, b := range readBuf[:n] {
    if b =='?'{   
        return true
    }
}
```